# How to move frame down in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, header-footer, margins, mdframed

I am writing one article using top and bottom margin.

```
 \usepackage[top=.5cm, bottom=.8cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, includefoot,showframe]{geometry}
```

I observe some spacing between frame and footer (here mdframed). How can i reduce spacing between footer and frame?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Maybe wikipedia is usefull here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_dimensions

Comment: `footskip`!....

Comment: The package `mdframed` doesn't use the page layout for drawing a frame. The splitting point is a little bit earlier and the frame is aligned at the top. It guess you are looking for something like the package `showframe` does.

Comment: Can i extend mdframed to bottom or top side.

Comment: @user15662: No. for your intention you should use the procedure of `showframe`

Answer (score 1):

`footskip` is the key to adjusting the gap between the footer and the main body text, even when using the `includefoot` key in [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry). Here's an example showing the difference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,geometry}
\geometry{top=5mm, bottom=8mm, left=1cm, right=1cm, includefoot, footskip=0pt, paperwidth=5cm, showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\newgeometry{top=5mm, bottom=8mm, left=1cm, right=1cm, includefoot, footskip=5pt}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

On the left is a `footskip` of `0pt`, while the right shows a `footskip` of `5pt`. The default document classes fixes this at `30pt`.